getting the error "permission denied" after writing the problem "newgrp docker" disappears for a short time
if you run the command "docker ps -a" an error occurs
"permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all =1": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"
when I use the "newgrp docker" command, the problem goes away for a while, but then this error occurs again.
How to fix it?
